# problemas con variable id en modal para modificar un registro php js

Tags: php, bootstrap, php7, variables, modal

buenas noches el inconveniente que presento es que cuando doy al boton modificar ubicado en una tabla y esta se desplega no me trae la informacion de la misma para poder hacer el update

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\copia\includes\functions\clases\datosclases2.php on line 6
```

la linea 6 es la siguiente  de datosclases2.php

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
```

seguido de (datosclases2.php):

```
         $results=$bd->query ("SELECT * from clases INNER JOIN docentes ON clases.id_docente_id = docentes.docentes_id  where clases_id='$id'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($results);

var_dump($id);
```

---

el error con el mostrado gracias al cosole.log es el siguiente

**C:\xampp\htdocs\cursos\includes\functions\clases\datosclases2.php** on line

el cual es el publicado en la imagen linea cuatro  es que no detecta el id del registro

o sea ** $id= $_POST['id'];** pero dentro del archivo donde se encuentra el formulario lo publico completo aqui abajo

entre directamente al archivo datosclases2.php y el error igualmente sale

```
<?php
include('../../../basedatos/conexion.php');

$id= $_POST['id'];

  $results=$bd->query ("SELECT * from clases INNER JOIN docentes ON clases.id_docente_id = docentes.docentes_id  where clases_id='$id'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($results);

var_dump($id);

?>



        <form>



          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Nombre de Clases:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_clases2" value="<?php echo $row['nombre_clases']?>">
          </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Nombre del Docente: </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="nombre_docente2">
            <option value="<?php echo $row['docentes_id']?>" selected>Nombre del Docente actual: <?php echo $row['nombre_docente']?></option>
              <option disabled>Seleccione un Docente Nuevo</option>
                <?php
                  while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row2['docentes_id']?>"><?php echo $row2['nombre_docente']?></option>
                    <?php
                  }
                ?>
            </select>
            
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Inicio de la Clase:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha_inicio2" value="<?php echo $row['fecha_inicio']?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Hora de inicio :</label>
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora_inicio2" value="<?php echo $row['hora_inicio']?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Hora final:</label>
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hora_fin2" value="<?php echo $row['hora_fin']?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Cantidad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad2" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad']?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Contenido:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contenido2" value="<?php echo $row['contenido']?>">
          </div>
        <br><br><br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Ubicacion del taller:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="directaller2" value="<?php echo $row['directaller']?>">
          </div>
  
        </form>
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1vQ4.png]

al ingresar en inspeccionar y buscar el cod el boton modificar si recibe el id del registro que se desea moficar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el parámetro `data` de la petición Ajax así: `data:{id: id},` si no funciona depura en el archivo php poniendo esto:  `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: al cololcoar el var_dump  aparece array(0) { }

Comment: acabo de modificar el query y me aparece NULL

Comment: `array(0) { }` significa que los datos no se están mandando. ¿Pusiste el parámetro `data` como te dije? Edita la pregunta para ver el código ahora. ¿En la consola ves un valor para el `id`? ¿Hay errores en la consola? Todo lo que te he señalado hasta ahora son cuestiones básicas de depuración que debes ir aprendiendo. Y, ¿a qué te refieres con *acabo de modificar el query*?

Comment: eso es todo lo q hice

Comment: Repetiste `data` dentro y usaste comillas, tiene que quedar justo así: `data:{id: id}`, no así: `data:"data:{id: id}"`, `data` es el nombre del parámetro para la petición Ajax en jQuery.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursos\includes\functions\clases\datosclases2.php on line 4
NULL

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta, quiero ver cómo quedó el código. Si lo escribiste bien no debería dar ese error. Y dime si ves errores en la consola.

Comment: Como está el código actualmente debería funcionar. ¿Activaste la consola de Javascript? ¿Muestra algún error? ¿Ves esto en consola: `console.log(id);` para más seguridad ponlo así: `console.log('Este es el ID:'+id);`

Comment: acabo de agregar el boton de actualizar

Comment: ¿El botón de actualizar? No entiendo qué quieres decir con eso.

Comment: en ese console.log coloco el numero del id ?

Comment: el boton que llama a la modal con el formularo

Comment: En el `console.log` que tienes en la parte de Ajax, pon un mensaje al lado y luego el valor de la variable `id`, luego abre la consola del navegador y revisa si imprime ese mensaje y el valor del id y revisa si la consola te informa de algún error. ¿Entiendes lo que te estoy diciendo? La consola se activa en el menú Desarrollador del navegador de internet que estés usando (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Internet Explorer u otro).

Comment: en el boton solo me sale el id del registro

Comment: ¿Y qué debe salir? Por favor edita la pregunta y explica lo que quieres lograr y lo que has depurado del código y los errores que tienes. El error era que los datos no estaban llegando a PHP, no entiendo a qué te refieres ahora con el botón. ¿Qué pasó con el problema del undefined index y el undefined variable, que era el error de la pregunta?

Comment: no aparece el msj escrito

Comment: listo ya lo edite

Comment: Muchas veces el problema es no saber explicar el problema. Eso es lo que ocurre aquí. O no sabes explicar el problema o no sabes cómo funciona Ajax. Por más que leo tu pregunta y las ediciones que has hecho de ella y todo lo que te he preguntado no logro obtener una explicación clara de lo que pasa. Para salir de este círculo te propongo lo siguiente: En la pregunta, primero explica lo que quieres lograr, luego explica cómo tienes organizado el código para lograr eso, luego muestra el código, di las depuraciones que has hecho y finalmente pon los errores que tienes.

Comment: editare la pregunta ps vi el error que me arroja el console log

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, hay algunas cosas a corregir, comenzando por el ID que estás asignando a los botones, de acuerdo a la [documentación para ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> **Nota:** El uso de caracteres a excepción de letras en ASCII, dígitos, '_', '-' y '.' pueden ocasionar problemas de compatibilidad, por no ser permitidos en HTML 4. A pesar de que esta limitación ha sido removida en HTML 5, ***un ID debe iniciar con una letra para asegurar la compatibilidad***.

Aprovecha que los botones son elementos de formulario y, por lo tanto, pueden tener el atributo `value` para especificar ahí el registro que deseas modificar; lo separé en varias líneas solo para verlo más fácil aquí.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
    value="<?php echo $ROWS['clases_id'];?>">Actualizar</button>
```

Luego, los botones tienen clase, pero tratas de obtenerlos por ID:

```
// El símbolo # es para obtener elementos por ID
$("#btn btn-outline-warning").each(function() {
```

Por supuesto, esta función nunca se va a ejecutar, porque los botones tienen clase y no ID, lo que me lleva a pensar que en alguna parte de tu código tienes otra función donde los obtienes por clase y es donde realmente está el error.

No es necesario (ni conveniente) que recorras los botones con `.each()` para asignar evento a cada uno, jQuery lo hará por ti y, de preferencia, asigna eventos con el método [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
// El punto es para obtener elementos por clase
$('.btn btn-outline-warning').on('click', function() {
    // Obtener ID desde valor del botón
    let id = $(this).val();
    $('#idclasesmodificar').val(id);
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/functions/clases/datosclases2.php",
        data:{id: id},
        // Especifica el tipo de datos que esperas recibir
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html){
            // ¿Esta línea es necesaria? Lee la parte final de la respuesta
            $("#Modal3").modal('show');
            $("#datosclases").html(html);
        },
        // Agrega una función de error para saber exactamente qué salió mal
        error: function(e, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Otro posible error es que en los botones estás asignando los atributos `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"` y se supone que Bootstrap (versión menor a 5) abrirá automáticamente la ventana modal con `id="exampleModal`, sin embargo, dentro de la petición AJAX intentas abrir otra modal con `id="Modal3"`.